# Where can I find the Solstheim enchanting table?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I am at Solstheim for the Dragonborn DLC and need to find an enchanting table. Where can I find one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solstheim is a big place with [8 Arcane Enchanters](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arcane_Enchanters#SolstheimDB).  There are even 3 in Raven Rock:  Councilor Morvayn's house, Ravenrock Mine & Severin Manor.

My 1st thought would be to go to Tel Mithryn, where you also have ready access to supplies & training.  Best of all, the door is never locked.

Answer (score 2):

There's one just inside the door and to the right in Morvayn Manor, the Councilor's house.